# Почему при добавлении свойства float:right второй блок смещается?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/anxR5/1/
При добавлении свойства float:right ко второму блоку, он смещается вниз на высоту первого блока. Интересно узнать из-за чего это происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за того, что сначала идет блочный елемент, который занимает 100% ширины, а следующий "плавающий" отображается там, где и должен, с "новой строки"

[Поменяйте их местами](http://jsfiddle.net/anxR5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/anxR5/3/ вот. просто добавь float:left; к первому элементу